# How to show big button without clicking button (clicking area around that button) in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I made many buttons for keyboard. When I click a button, it is shown as big button. Without clicking button, can it be shown as big button ?(like iPhone) Could you give some example codes ?

Like you see in this picture (the default one), I just click near/around button, not button directly, but it shows letter in textfield ! How to set condition of area around the button ?

[image: without clicking button]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are doing, can up add some pictures and a better description please.

Comment: Could you clarify a little? Are you talking about a text keyboard?

Comment: you can see in the picture above, I don't click it directly !

Comment: beside UIControlStateTouchUpInside, UIControlStateTouchDown, what else can we use to know the touch area ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to having a larger image of the button show up over top of the highlighted button, like the keyboard?

If so, I'd look into setting an action for UIControlStateTouchDown to see when your button is highlighted, and ultimately add that larger button image over top of the pressed button.  Then, add an action for UIControlStateTouchUpInside, UIControlStateTouchUpOutside, and UIControlStateTouchCancel to remove your larger button image.

To keep track of the larger button image, you could use properties and keep track of it.  I'd recommend subclassing UIButton, which I presume you are using for your button, and add a property for its larger button image so the larger button image is tied to the button that it is over top of.

Comment: What aren't you clear about?  I doubt that if I provide code, you will be any clearer about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your post isn't very clear but I believe you are trying to duplicate the button zooming functionality of the `UIKeyboard`.

If this is the case then here are couple of simple steps to make this happen.

Add custom actions to the button for the control states "touch up inside" and "touch down". 
I would probably do this in `viewDidAppear` so that you aren't jamming up the run loop until everything is done moving into place. Maybe performing this on a slight delay may even be beneficial. Doing this in a loop as demonstrated below will allow you to automatically add these actions to every object of the class "UIButton" in your main view's array of subviews.

```
    for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(anyButtonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(anyButtonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

We will use the touch down method to zoom the button, and touch up inside to return the button to its original state and then append the buttons text value to the end of your text field.

For the sake of this example, I've used a `UILabel`.

Notice on these methods we are using `UIButton` as an argument so that the transform of which ever button called this action can be transformed without having to create an action for every button.

```
- (void)anyButtonDown:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:sender];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [sender setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -25))];
    }];
}
```

And here we adjust "sender"s transform back to its original transform when the button is released. This animation is created with a completion handler to allow the text designated for that button to be appended to the end of the text that is currently in the label when the button is done animating back to its original state.

**NOTE:** For this to work I am assuming that you have entered the letter that the button represents as the button's `textLabel`.

```
- (void)anyButtonUp:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [sender setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0))];
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        [textLabel setText:[textLabel.text stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text]];
    }];
}
```

Comment: for default keyboard, how to disable keys (not showing in big button) ?